# The index pattern you've entered doesn't match any indices

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, log4j2

I create new index via log4j2 appender for elasticsearch. When I call link http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices I can see the indices which I created. But in Kibana when I try to create index pattern, Kibana can't find my index. Could anyone please help me. Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Kibana cant match your pattern because all of the log4j2 are empty.

There is a bug opened about this : https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/15666